# iPad virtual keyboard - which one - javasctript solution?

Tags: javascript, ipad

It seems there are several different layouts of the iPad virtual keyboard when it appears for example a user clicks a text field on a web site... is there a way to determine which is shown?

e.g. I have a sign in page which requires a user to enter their email address, therefore, I'd like the virtual keyboard to show with the @ symbol on the first page as opposed to having to select the symbols shift when a user clicks in a text field to enter their email address.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="email" />
```

You can control the keyboard shown by adjusting the input type accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to read [this article](http://uxmovement.com/forms/input-types-give-users-the-right-keyboard-on-mobile-forms/). 
It's very complete about how many different keyboards you can show to your users...

Comment: Very helpful, many thanks - surprisingly hard to find much info on this - I guess not enough people care about a great UI!

Answer (score 1):

Html5 introduced several new input types, they can display different virtual keyboards.

Check http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_type.asp

Comment: Yes, I know, although the referenced page contains the input types correctly